# PHP + UnixODBC + FreeTDS - SELECT [field] AS [name] does not work

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, freetds, unixodbc

I have a unix server which has PHP 5.2.13 installed, and it has access to two SQL servers (one is running MSSQL SERVER 2000 and the other MSSQL 2005).

It uses FreeTDS - details:

- Version: freetds v0.82
- freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/etc
- MS db-lib source compatibility: no
- Sybase binary compatibility: no
- Thread safety: yes
- iconv library: yes
- TDS version: 8.0
- iODBC: no
- unixodbc: yes

And I'm using unixODBC-2.3.1

The MSSQL 2000 server is fine, I can run all SQL statements and use mssql_num_rows and mssql_fetch_assoc much as you would with MySQL.

However, the MSSQL 2005 server won't work with mssql_num_rows or mssql_fetch_assoc - you have to use odbc_fetch_row.

That's not really an issue, I assum it's just due to the different server installs.

However, I have a huge issue with the MSSQL 2005 server: I cannot select a field AS another name!

For example:

```
SELECT
   [EnquiryID] AS "The_Key"
   FROM [db].[dbo].[table]
```

Works fine in my admin application (ie: NOT PHP), but if I run the same in my PHP environment, I get:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [PK_EnquiryID] => 1
)
```

You can see it should be `[The_Key] => 1`

Has anyone any idea how we can get round this, please?  I'm tearing my hair out!

Cheers

Neil

Answer (score 1):

I think this was answered on the freeTDS list, but the problem in is PHP, it makes the wrong call to ODBC so gets the base table name instead of the lable which is what you need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a perfect solution, and I would love to learn the proper way to deal with this issue, but in the mean time, add

```
+''
```

to each column, after the underlying column name, but before the AS alias and you should be able to circumvent this issue.